# How to see read errors with rsync like using scp?

Tags: unix, rsync, scp

When copying something using `scp`, you get clear read errors (I/O Errors) in the output.

How can you tell `rsync` to report read errors like `scp`?

```
scp: /home/abc/a0/0f/4e/7d-2a4b-4be0-ac7b-7f93c1706edf.pdf:
Input/output error
```

I need a way to detect read errors while synching with `rsync`.

Commands used:

```
scp -r root@XYZ:/home/abc .  
rsync -av --delete-before --rsync-path "ionice -c 3 nice rsync" --bwlimit=30000 root@XYZ:/home/abc .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `rsync -v` and you wish more verbosity, there is no option that would show more information about the file transfer.

So `-v` is already the highest level of verbosity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use --verbose switch to increase verbosity of output ?

Comment: I did that. But if there is an I/O Error on the reading side (server), I don't see that in the logs... But I should know when such an error occurs, like scp does.